# how to create a thumbnail of a webpage in Qt/QML for android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, thumbnails

I am developing an app for android on Qt and i want to have thumbnail previews of webpages on certain items. I have been looking everywhere but I can't really find anything except for one post from Nokia where they build an app that creates thumbnails.

The problem is that this app uses "Qt+= webkitwidgets" which is not supported by android so i need to find another way.

**Would there be any other way to create a thumbnail of a webpage besides using these classes:**

```
QWebPage
QWebFrame
QWebSettings
```

As they are part of the webkitwidgets module

Comment: Have a look on the Thumbnailer example of the QWebPage: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebpage.html#details

Comment: @danielfranca  see, thats the problem. QWebPage is part of webkitwidgets, which is not supported on android.

Comment: did you try QWebEngine? As I know it supports Android from 5.4 or earlier. Anyway, to make thumbnail of a webpage you must have HTML renderer, so it have to be a start point. If you can find a Qt widget which can render HTML you can find answer to your question.

Comment: @folibis yes, I figured. First thing ill need to do i get the HTML source from a QWebEngine or either capture a frame from it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do the creation of thumbnails in a serverside application. This way the android device is not bothered with these things.